# PHP syntax $obj->{'somekey'}

Tags: php, syntax

I came across this code

```
$user = new stdClass();
$user->{'approved'} = 'No';
```

I searched PHP docs and Google and can't get to an answer as to why this syntax would be used as opposed to:

```
$user = new stdClass();
$user->approved = 'No';
```

Comment: I think this is a developer's choice. There is no real reason to not use the latter one.

Comment: Incase you've got a syntax collision, you can use that notation bracketd/quoted notation, you can do some dumb things too `$object->{'->'} = 'foo';`

Comment: This is documented in the [Variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php#example-86) section. In this case, both options are equivalent. If you have a property name that's either dynamic or not a valid identifier, the first one is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

The reason *I* use this is because my IDE (PhpStorm) does not know what properties the instance has and marks usages of `$user->approved` as an undefined property while using `$user->{'approved'}` as valid. This especially happens when loading data from an external source (e.g. an API call).

Other than that, I'd say it's matter of developer preference.

Answer (score 0):

This type of code is for future amendments, and put here temporary/static value at the time of first development.

```
$user = new stdClass();
$user->{'approved'} = 'No';
```

The syntax `{'value'}` is for dynamic property element, you can use it like

```
$dynamicVal = 'approved';
$user->{$dynamicVal} = 'No';
```

Comment: *This type of code is for future amendments, and put here temporary/static value at the time of first development.* How do you know what the intention of the creator was?

Comment: @Daan : I can just say either the code creator don't know that both code are same as OP given. Or the intention was to put a variable in future.